# Alteração no HTACCESS: URL Rewritre para inserir domínio

Tags: php, htaccess, url-rewrite

Bom dia!

Tenho um site funcionando hoje na Locaweb, e ele tem apresentado diversos problemas de lentidão e acreditamos ser o servidor.

Estamos tentando migrar para a Hostgator para testar, e estamos usando o endereço provisório de acesso. Mas, essa URL tem um diretório na URL para acessar (http://br820.hostgator.com.br/~gpapr829/), e tem comprometido meu sistema de URL amigável.

Meu código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # URL Amigável
    RewriteRule ^(common|sistema|upload)($|/) - [L]
    RewriteRule !\.(css|js|xml|bmp|swf|flv|ico|html|pdf|woff|ttf|svg|eot|zip|mp3|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|ai|eps|ico)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Quando eu deixo esse código ativo, ele sequer entra no site. Tive que comentar os RewriteRules para poder acessar a home. Acredito que seja decorrente do segundo RewriteRule ter o index.php. Porém, tentei ajustar colocando o diretório:

```
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|xml|bmp|swf|flv|ico|html|pdf|woff|ttf|svg|eot|zip|mp3|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|ai|eps|ico)$ ~gpapr829/index.php [L]
```

Resultado: Erro 500.

Tentei também:

```
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|xml|bmp|swf|flv|ico|html|pdf|woff|ttf|svg|eot|zip|mp3|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|ai|eps|ico)$ "/~gpapr829/index.php" [L]
```

Não dá erro 500, mas também não funciona. Vai para 404 do servidor.

O que posso fazer neste caso?

Comment: Você já verificou se o mod_rewrite está ativo? Vc pode ver isso com o `phpinfo();`  Coloque esta função em um script de teste e execute, no resultado procure a linha em que aparace **Loaded Modules** e veja se o mod_rewrite está na lista de módulos habilitados do apache.

Comment: Sim, verifiquei e está ativo sim! Senão, ele nem entrava na condicional do IfModule. Mas também pensei que pudesse ser algo assim.